# Calculating the total commissions that sellers will receive based on the number of products they sell

Tags: sum, google-sheets-formula, vlookup, percentage, calculation

We have three tables, first table define the commission rate percentages, second table has the products, sold price and the seller  name.

On third table must have calculated the total commission of each sellers.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NAmA8NFAKpA4S0QszIKNP-HeDQCaXm2jCbcpS3eXEZE/edit?usp=sharing

[Table definitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3Qd1.png)

I can only calculate small rate percentages. it does not work if commission rate table has too many rows.

Comment: Showcase us the ideal expected output numbers for those 2 sellers (**by calculating it manually**) & some noob explanation on how you arrived at those specific value(s) so that we can create the formula based on the given logic.

Comment: I have added a solution but it is not the solution.

Answer (score 0):

*You may test:*

```js
=map(I2:I,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",, sumif(F:F,Σ,G:G) * xlookup(countif(F:F,Σ),B:B,C:C,,1))))
```

[image]